# How to select all columns where one column has rows that end with '006'

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, ends-with

I'm using dplyr and I want to select all the columns on the table but return only the rows where one specific column ends with `'006'`.

```r
select(sample_id, ends_with("006"), everything())
```

The code above doesn't work. When I run it, it returns all rows (or more than I need -- it's a huge dataset).

I've tried using:

```r
filter(sample_id == ends_with('006'))
```

but `ends_with()` needs to be used within a select function.

Comment: `filter(stringr::str_sub(sample_id, -3, -1) == “006”)`. `ends_with()` selects columns. You want to filter rows.

Comment: oh, interesting! So ends_with selects columns only. makes complete sense now.

Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_ends` from package `stringr`:

```
df %>% filter(str_ends(sample_id, "006"))
```

By default the pattern is a regular expression. You can match a fixed string with:

```
df %>% filter(str_ends(sample_id, fixed("006")))
```

Of course it's also possible to use a more general regular expression. It's useful if you have a more complex pattern to check, but it also works here:

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(sample_id, "006$"))
```

See also: [Detect the presence or absence of a pattern at the beginning or end of a string](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_starts.html).

Answer (score 1):

`ends_with()` is for subseting columns. You should use `endsWith()` from `base`:

```r
filter(endsWith(sample_id, "006"))
```

It's equivalent to

```r
filter(grepl("006$", sample_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a base R approach, we could use `grepl` here along with a data frame subset operation:

```r
df_out <- df[grepl("006$", df$sample_id), ]
```

Comment: How would this be used within a chain? I'm using pipe operators.

Comment: @Antonio `df %>% filter(grepl("006$", sample_id))`.